# How to open a pdf file from a notification

Tags: android, pdf, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have to open a pdf after clicking on a notification. I tried to do this:

```
public void addNotification(File file) {
    createNotificationChannel();


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "0");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    builder.setContentTitle(file.getName() + " creato");
    builder.setContentText("Il tuo pdf è stato salvato nella cartella download");
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(0, builder.build());
}

public void createNotificationChannel(){
    CharSequence name = "Personal";
    String description = "";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("0", name, importance);
        notificationChannel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

}
```

it seems to work because the pdf reader app is launched, but the file is not opened and i don't get any error.

Comment: Replace the last `0` in your `PendingIntent.getActivity()` call with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` and see if that helps. If not, try using your `Intent` directly via `startActivity()`. If it works, then your problem lies somewhere in the `PendingIntent` and notification. If `startActivity()` also fails, though, then there is some issue with the file perhaps.

Comment: add description and see set the path of the file in the intent and pick it up in the activity opened by it.

Comment: @CommonsWare everything you suggest fail, any ideas about file problem?

Comment: If you are saying that `startActivity()` fails, then perhaps the file is corrupt or something. You might consider writing a test case that tests how you create the file, to confirm that the file is created correctly.